# Google MLKit translate duplicated word in translation

Tags: android, google-mlkit

When we use Google MLKit to translate we get occasional duplicated words.

```
About that time the abufes and rantable praices ralating to to. the the ations againft the Co Company

 அந்த நேரத்தில் abufes மற்றும் rantable praines to ralating. ations ations ations ations ations ations டு கம்பெனி
```

We see **"ations"** getting duplicated a few times in the translation as **"ations ations ..."**. This happens occasionally when it can't translate a word. Did anyone face this issue and is there a solution short of explicitly filtering out the duplicated words from the translation?

We use the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.2'
```